# Easy way to make changes in a class?

Tags: lyx, document-classes, lyx-layouts, modules

I'm using the article (Hebrew) class for my document.

I'm using the "theorem" and "proof" modules (I hope that's the correct term), and I'd like to make very simple changes.
For example, make "Proof" underlined, and add ":" at the end.

After a short search I've come to the conclusion that modifying classes isn't a very simple matter for beginners.

Since I'm short of time, I'd just like to know if the changes I want to make are difficult, and if not, what would the steps needed be.

(In my mind I'd simply need to locate the class' source, edit a couple of tex lines and save. Is it that simple?)

Comment: You should not edit the class files, any definition within the class may be over-written by definitions in your document preamble.

Comment: It is never a good idea to change a class file itself, any command can be redefined with some more or less effort with, say `\renewcommand` and its relatives or, if needed by `\def` statements.

Comment: If you really do need to change the class file, copy the file to a different name in your personal `texmf` tree e.g. `${TEXMFHOME}/tex/latex/custom-class/custom-class.cls` and edit that copy. Then use `custom-class` with `\documentclass`.

Comment: The class doesn't have anything to do with formatting of the theorems and proofs. You can edit the module, or use the local layout (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164234/changing-theoremams-in-lyx/166133#166133). You need to define a new `\theoremstyle` (see manual for `amsthm`). I don't know exactly how to make *Proof* underlined though. However, considering you were short on time I suppose your deadline has expired ...