# Changing Theorem(AMS) in Lyx

Tags: lyx, amsthm

I use the theorem(AMS) module in Lyx.
If i use the Lemma, Definition etc. enviroment then Lemma for example is written in bold letters.
If i use the remark enviroment its in italic. I would like to change it, so that it is in bold as well. How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There was a similar question a while back, perhaps it can be helpful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129770

Answer (score 6):

Go to Document --> Settings --> Local Layout, add the below code, click Validate and OK. This will set the `Remark` style to the same as `Lemma`. If you want this style for many documents, create a new module as described in [How to make "claim" environments look like "theorem" environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129770)

```
Style Remark
CopyStyle             Theorem
DependsOn         Theorem
LatexName             rem
LabelString           "Remark \thetheorem."
Font
  Shape               Up
  Size                Normal
EndFont
LabelFont
  Shape                Up
  Series              Italic
EndFont
Preamble
  \theoremstyle{plain}
  \newtheorem{rem}[thm]{\protect\remarkname}
EndPreamble
LangPreamble
  \providecommand{\remarkname}{_(Remark)}
EndLangPreamble
BabelPreamble
  \addto\captions$$lang{\renewcommand{\remarkname}{_(Remark)}}
EndBabelPreamble
End
```

[image]

Comment: Great job, TT!!